# In Python, how do I create a new object of the same type as an old object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Suppose that we have an object `x`, but we do not know which class `x` is instantiated from. We want to create a new object `y` of the same type as `x`.

If we knew which class x was instantiated from, we could simply call the class constructor/initializer:

```
y = NameOfClass()
```

However, we do not know the name of the class x is instantiated from.

The main question can be broken down into two sub-questions:

1) How do I find out what datatype x is?
2) Given a datatype (stored somewhere in the computer) how do I create a new object of that type?

Answer (score 0):

```
NameOfClass = type(x)
y = NameOfClass()
```

Comment: That's assuming the class actually *has* a constructor that works that way.

Comment: What if it takes parameters? You can’t assume this will work. The `__repr__` *might*, if correctly constructed, show you how to recreate at least some of the state, but there’s no guarantee.